# keyboard avoid view not enough height

Tags: react-native

keyboard pushes "CreateComment" component to top but not enough height ,it's still hides the "CreateComment" component which it includes "InputText"

```
     <ScrollView >
                 ....
      </ScrollView> 

     <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
      <View  style={styles.footer}>
       <CreateComment GetComments={()=>this.GetComments()}
        roomId={this.state.postID} />
       </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView> 

</View>
```

and here is stlye:

```
container: {
flex: 1, 
},
footer :{ 
 position:'absolute',
 bottom:0 },
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the height you want to specify yourself.

You can use `offset`

**Example**

```js
<KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior="position"
          keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
        >
```

Comment: @isme If my answer was helpful, would you please check and select the 'V' and arrow?